# So say I have a directory like this

Tags: php, file

Folder

File1.txt

File2.txt

File3.txt

File4.txt

File5.txt

File6.txt

File7.txt

File8.txt

File9.txt

But whenever I add another file it looks like this

File1.txt

File10.txt //NEW FILE

File2.txt

File3.txt

File4.txt

File5.txt

File6.txt

File7.txt

File8.txt

File9.txt
And mabey I add another file

File1.txt

File10.txt //NEW FILE

File11.txt //NEWER FILE

File2.txt

File3.txt

File4.txt

File5.txt

File6.txt

File7.txt

File8.txt

File9.txt

And as you can guess when I include all these files in one PHP file
It messes up...

Say that file1.txt has the contents :1

File10.txt has the contents :10

File2.txt has the contents :2

File3.txt has the contents :3

And so on

When I include this the order on the page appears as this

1

10

2

3

4

5

And so on

So how do I get the files to appear in number order???

Here is the code I'm working with

```
<?php


// Add correct path to your countlog.txt file.
$path = 'ChatNumbers.txt';

// Opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits.
$file  = fopen( $path, 'r' );
$count = fgets( $file, 1000 );
fclose( $file );

// Update the count

$count = abs( intval( $count ) ) + "1";



// Opens countlog.txt to change new hit number.
$file = fopen( $path, 'w' );
fwrite( $file, $count);
fclose( $file );
 $ab = 'Chat_';
 $cn = "$count";
 $rp = '.html';
 $fr = "$ab$cn$rp";
 $path = "Chats/$fr";

  if (isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['field1'].'<p></p>';
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }


?>
```

And This is how I am currently including my files

```
<php
foreach (glob("chat/Chats/*.html") as $filename)
{
   include $filename;
   }
?>
```

Comment: So sort them???  Without code we can't help. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: Can you name your files with leading zeroes? `file001.txt, file002.txt, ... file010.txt`

Comment: I could rename them with following 0s but then I have thousands of html files in my directory as I use it as a database and file numbers are always increasing so I would have to keep updating my script

Comment: How could I adjust my code to an array sort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way to go about all of this I'm sure, but to answer the question, you need to sort (naturally):

```
$files = glob("chat/Chats/*.html");
natsort($files);

foreach ($files as $filename)
{
   include $filename;
}
```